# Creating a separate thread to read from a 2 way serial port in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to read data from a serial port and for that I need a separate thread which will run in the background and continously check for 'whether data is available to be read', further the serial port is two way(rx-tx).  One way to do this is to add a serial event listener but i'm not getting how to make a background thread to do the same, help me please!

I have made a class read, which takes an input stream from some other class and I am making a thread of this read class so that it runs in the background to see if any recieve event is triggered, but the recieving isn't happening, what's the problem, anyone?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;


public class read implements SerialPortEventListener, Runnable {

InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort sp;
public read(SerialPort sp, InputStream input){

    inputStream = input;
    this.sp = sp;
    try {
        sp.addEventListener(this);
} catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    sp.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
/*    try{
        sp.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}*/

        new Thread(this).start();

}

@Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1000];

        try {
            while (true) {

                int numBytes;
                if(inputStream.available() > 0){

                    numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);

                }
                else
                    break;

            }
             System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
             try{
    inputStream.close();
    sp.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: there, i have updated the question, have a look

Comment: Your Runnable is doing nothing. Actually, the thread will sleep for 20 seconds and after it is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read data from a serial port and for that I need a separate thread which will run in the background and continously check for 'whether data is available to be read'

No you don't. You need a listener. You already have a listener. You've added it to the serial port. You don't need anything else. You don't need to start the listener as a thread. It is a callback object that JavaComm will call automatically.

> further the serial port is two way(rx-tx). One way to do this is to add a serial event listener but i'm not getting how to make a background thread to do the same ...

That's because you don't have to do it. You've misunderstood how the listener works. When the listener fires, the code in the appropriate callback method is executed. That's it. No thread required on your part.

> I have made a class read, which takes an input stream from some other class

Correct.

> and I am making a thread of this read class so that it runs in the background to see if any recieve event is triggered

Unnecessary and pointless, see above.

> but the recieving isn't happening, what's the problem, anyone?

You're doing it wrong. Remove the thread, remove the `run()` method, remove the `start()`, and just wait for events to be delivered to the callback methods.

Re your code:

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1000];

    try {
        while (true) {
```

Remove the loop.

```
            int numBytes;
            if(inputStream.available() > 0){
```

Remove the test. It is already true, that's what falling into `case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE` means.

```
                numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            else
                break;
```

Remove this `else` and `break`.

```
         System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
```

Change to

```
         System.out.print(new String(readBuffer, 0, numBytes));
```

You're ignoring the length returned by `read()`, so you're constructing a `String` including junk at the end of the buffer beyond what was read.

```
         try{
inputStream.close();
sp.close();
}
```

Remove all this. You should not close the input stream just because there is no data presently available to be read. Leave it open. At present you are closing the stream, and therefore disabling the listener, after the first piece of data arrives.